Running Keycloak with SQL Server local database
I'm learning Docker and I have a question that is certainly simple, but I haven't found it anywhere yet: I want a Keycloak container to connect to the SQL Server database that is installed locally on my machine - that is, the database data is not in container.
I saw in some places that if a container wanted to connect to a specific port on my machine it could use host.docker.internal. But would this work for databases?
See, I set up this very simple docker-compose to test this solution, but I haven't managed to do it yet, because whenever the container starts running, an error is returned.
docker-compose
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    environment:
      KC_DB: mssql
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:sqlserver://host.docker.internal:1433;databaseName=Keycloak;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=true;loginTimeout=30
      KC_DB_USERNAME: xxx
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: yyy
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "4000:8080"
    command:
      - start-dev
    restart: always

Container logs:
Updating the configuration and installing your custom providers, if any. Please wait.
2024-07-21 01:19:18,531 INFO  [io.qua.dep.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Quarkus augmentation completed in 4866ms
2024-07-21 01:19:21,968 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller'
2024-07-21 01:19:26,794 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA Startup Thread) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot throw exception because the return value of "java.util.function.BiFunction.apply(Object, Object)" is null
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.doTheWork(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:202)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.lambda$delegateWork$3(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.doInSuspendedTransaction(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:276)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:136)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:247)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.<init>(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:276)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.recording.PrevalidatedQuarkusMetadata.buildSessionFactoryOptionsBuilder(PrevalidatedQuarkusMetadata.java:70)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.build(FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:84)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.java:72)
        at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
        at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$LazyPersistenceUnit.get(JPAConfig.java:157)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$1.run(JPAConfig.java:64)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

2024-07-21 01:19:27,287 INFO  [org.keycloak.broker.provider.AbstractIdentityProviderMapper] (main) Registering class org.keycloak.broker.provider.mappersync.ConfigSyncEventListener
2024-07-21 01:19:27,303 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (main) Node name: node_489463, Site name: null
2024-07-21 01:19:32,311 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] (main) ARJUNA032014: Stopping transaction recovery manager
2024-07-21 01:19:32,372 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
2024-07-21 01:19:32,372 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to obtain JDBC connection
2024-07-21 01:19:32,372 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Acquisition timeout while waiting for new connection

I've already tried changing the connection string and also using network_mode: host but nothing worked.

Have you looked in the SQL Server's ERRORLOG file, or via the SSMS tool in Server > Management > SQL Server Logs > Current, to see if it's getting login failure messages? i.e.: if you're seeing 18456 Login Failed messages there then take note of the State number(s) and compare them against those listed at MSSQLSERVER_18456 to see why the login attempts are actually failing.

Have you tried checking if your local database is listening on port 1433 -- ensure the database endpoint is valid: jdbc:sqlserver://{your ip}:1433;databaseName=Keycloak;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=true;loginTimeout=30

Connect to your SQL Server either in docker or hosted on azure and Create the database by hand. Rerun Keycloak and it should work just fine

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
